# How to remove a repetitive pattern with the same beginning and ending in text files

Tags: python, python-re

I am working with multiple txt files that contain **repetitive** sentences with the format below:

> "[TEXT1]File. Title:[TEXT2]____________ [TEXT3]File. Title:[TEXT4]____________[TEXT5]"

*TEXT: Contains words,\n,\t, number, spaces, punctuations

I want to remove **all** sentences that starts with 'File. Title:' and ends with '____________' from the text. This is the output I'm looking for:

> "[TEXT1][TEXT3][TEXT5]"

The actual text looks like:

> "xxxxx  \n\t, \tFile. Title:\tVersion 2.0\t\n____________"

Unfortunately, the code I used removed everything between the first occurrence of "File. Title" and the last occurrence of "Version 2.0". I'm wondering if there's a solution that can better solve my problem?

Here's the code that I used.

```
text = re.sub('File. Title:\s.*\sVersion 2.0','',text, flags = re.DOTALL)
text = text.replace("____________", "")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "[TEXT1]File. Title:[TEXT2]____________[TEXT3]File. Title:[TEXT4]____________[TEXT5]"

def filter_texts(s):
    start = 'File. Title:'
    end = '____________'
    s2 = s.replace(start, f'splitmarker{start}').replace(end, f'{end}splitmarker')
    s2 = s2.split('splitmarker')
    s2 = filter(lambda ss: not (ss.startswith(start) and ss.endswith(end)), s2)
    s2 = ''.join(s2)
    return s2

print(filter_texts(s))
```

prints

```
[TEXT1][TEXT3][TEXT5]
```

This codes replaces each start marker (i.e. `'File. Title:'`) with *split marker concantenated with start marker* and each end marker (i.e. `'____________'`) with *end marker concatenated with split maker* (where split maker is simply a string that (hopefully) does not occur otherwise, here set to `'splitmarker'`) such that when the string is then split by the split marker, one can filter the resulting list of texts directly by the desired condition, (i.e. *text does not start with start marker or does not end with end marker*). Note that while this does the trick, there probably exist much more elegant solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This completely solved my problem!